# Refrescar DIV usando AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

estaba tratando de dar ME GUSTA a una publicación e intentar que no me refrescara la pagina, sino que solo se refrescara el DIV.

Archivo megusta.php:

```
<?php

function darMeGusta($id_usuario, $id_publicacion)
{
    include 'php/conBD.php';
    if(!isMeGusta($id_usuario, $id_publicacion))
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO megusta (usuario, publicacion) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$id_publicacion')";
        $execute = mysqli_query($conBD, $query);
    }
}
function isMeGusta($id_usuario, $id_publicacion)
{
    include 'php/conBD.php';
    $megusta = false;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM megusta WHERE usuario = '$id_usuario' AND publicacion = '$id_publicacion'";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conBD, $query);
    if($execute)
    {
        if($num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($execute) == 1)
        {
            $megusta = true;
        }
    }
    return $megusta;
}
function quitarMeGusta($id, $id_publicacion)
{
    include 'php/conBD.php';
    $query = "DELETE FROM megusta WHERE usuario = '$id' AND publicacion = '$id_publicacion'";
    $execute = mysqli_query($conBD, $query);
}
?>
```

Y aqui el archivo html:

```
            <?php
            $test = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY fecha DESC";
            $execute = mysqli_query($conBD, $test);
            if($execute)
            {
                while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($execute))
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <?php echo getUsuarioById($result['usuario'])?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <?php echo $result['publicacion'] ?>
                            <br>
                            <form action="" method="POST" id="me_form">
                                    <div style="display: flex">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id-publicacion" value="<?php echo $result['id']?>">
                                            <input id="darMG" name="btn-dar-megusta" type="submit" class="btn btn-link" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey; width: 50%; <?php if(isMegusta($id, $result['id'])) echo 'background: rgb(83, 151, 188); color: white;' ?>" value="Me gusta">
                                    </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Vi que usando AJAX llamaban a un archivo PHP que hacia una cosa en especifico como comentar o dar me gusta, en mi caso dentro del archivo PHP tengo varias funciones y no se como manejarlo xd.

Si alguien puede ayudarme con eso o recomendarme algún libro o vídeo o lo que sea me seria de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Te guio un poco con la idea, deberias tener los siguientes archivos:

`archivo.php` (este muestra el html con el boton de me gusta)

`like.php` (este recibe el id del post, guarda el valor y devuelve algo)

`ajax.js` (archivo javascript que hace el ajax)

```
// archivo.php
<div class="card">
  [...]
  <div class="favs  <?php if(isMegusta($id, $result['id'])){?>active<?php }?>" data-id="<?php echo $result['id']?>">5</div>
  [...]
</div>
```

```
// like.php
$id = $_GET['id']

[...Procesas y todo]

echo "guardado". // O devolves un JSON lo que quieras.
```

```
//ajax.js
var favs = document.querySelectorAll( '.favs' );

for( var i = 0; i < favs.length; i++ ){
    favs[i].addEventListener( 'click', onClickFav, false );
}

function onClickFav(){
  if ( this.classList.contains( 'active' ) ) {
    return;
  }

  sendAjax( this );
}
function sendAjax( button ){
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
     if ( request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
        //Si responde OK validas si el dato se guardo o no, y luego le sumas uno al numero del contenido
        botton.textContent = parseInt( botton.textContent, 10 ) + 1;
      } else if( request.readyState == 4 && request.status != 200 ){
        // ACA hubo un error
      }
   }
   request.open( "GET", "like.php?id"+button.dataset.id, true );
   request.send();
}
```

Espero que te sirva la idea.